# how to concatenate lookup fields given certain circumstances

Tags: apex, batch, string, if

I finished up this batch but came across an unforeseen scenario and can't seem to figure out how to code in the case it occurs. Here is my current code:

```
global class Batch implements Database.Batchable<sObject>, Database.Stateful, Schedulable {
global String query = 'SELECT Id, Account__c, Book_of_Business__c, Status__c, Book_of_Business__r.Level__c, Book_of_Business__r.Relationship_Owner__c, Book_of_Business__r.Type__c FROM Account_BOB__c ' +
   'WHERE Status__c = Active' +
   'AND Effective_Date__c = TODAY';

public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {       
    return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
}

public void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Account_BOB__c> scope) { 
    Map<Id, Account> accMap = new Map<Id, Account>();
    
     for(Account_BOB__c accBOB : scope) { 
         Account acc;
         if (accMap.containsKey(accBOB.Account__c)) {
             acc = accMap.get(accBOB.Account__c);
         }
         if (accBOB.Book_of_Business__r.Level__c == 'External I') {
             acc.Annuity_External_1__c = accBOB.Book_of_Business__r.Relationship_Owner__c;
         }
         if (accBOB.Book_of_Business__r.Level__c == 'External II') {
             acc.Annuity_External_2__c = accBOB.Book_of_Business__r.Relationship_Owner__c;
         }
         if (accBOB.Book_of_Business__r.Level__c == 'Internal' && accBOB.Book_of_Business__r.Type__c == 'Level 3') {
             acc.Annuity_Internal_Rep__c = accBOB.Book_of_Business__r.Relationship_Owner__c;
         }
         if (accBOB.Book_of_Business__r.Level__c == 'Internal' && accBOB.Book_of_Business__r.Type__c == 'Level 2') {
             acc.Annuity_Internal_Rep_2__c = accBOB.Book_of_Business__r.Relationship_Owner__c;
         }
         accMap.put(acc.Id, acc);
     }    
    if(!accMap.IsEmpty())  
        Database.Update(accMap.values(),false);
}
```

The issue is shown in this screenshot. There are multiple different Book of Businesses with the same level. [image] In this scenario, the corresponding field on Account should show both relationship owners, not just one. These fields are both lookup(user) data type.  How should I alter my code so that if there are multiple Book of Businesses with the same Level (and Type) it takes both of the corresponding owners?

Thanks in advance!

Edit- I think the approach I will take if there are multiple options is instead of updating a lookup field, I'll update a new text field to hold the concatenated values. How should I adjust my code accordingly though?

Comment: What would the page look like when there's more than 1?

Comment: the same, the field i'm updating would just have multiple names instead of one

Answer (score 0):

Consider any of these two options:

1)
A limitation of Lookup Fields is that they can only hold/accept one record Id. Therefore instead of Lookup you could use a Text field (of adequate length to hold your combined/concatenated values). Then adjust your code to write the concatenates/combined data values to the Text field when needed.

2)
Alternatively you could consider keeping the Lookup field model but change how you are viewing the information; for example try using a Matrix Report, and group by datapoints that you see as redundant, as one way to tidy up the display of information.

Comment: I think I will go with if there are multiple options to instead of updating a lookup field, I'll update a new text field to hold the concatenated values. How would I adjust my code accordingly though?

Comment: by using text instead of lookup you lose a host of reporting luxuries, because the join is not there as it is in lookups. As for the code maybe another responder can help, but mine is limited currently; you may want to loop your results (using a Map or for loop) , compare, and use the + operator to build such a string. Consider editing your post to include any // commented attempts of the concatentation piece and perhaps someone can help you where you get stuck.